# My grails app fails on cloudfoundry after 3000 http calls from a test program

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I've run 80,000 http calls thru my grails app running on my desktop PC and it did not fail. On cloudfoundry, the same app runs out of memory after about 3000 http calls. The app uses MySql, Mongodb, and RabbitMQ. On Cloudfoundry, I have increased the memory to 1G using the VMC command.  While the test program is running, I can watch the memory usage with the VMC stats command and the memory usage grows up to 1G and the app fails.  I'm using Grails 2.0.1 on my local machine.

What could be causing this problem?

Could it be related to this: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=73 ?

Answer (score 1):

You might get some use out of [this post](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/) as your test app is likely much like a batch application.

You should use jconsole to monitor your application when running locally and set your local memory allocated to java to the same values as cloudfoundry to see if you can reproduce the error.  If jconsole shows that you're never letting go of memory, then you likely have a leak and aren't allowing things to get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

For Java web apps you need to also set the Xmx:

```
vmc set-env APP JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M"
```